# Nutch 2.0 and Hadoop. How to prevent caching of conf/regex-urlfilter.txt

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I have nutch 2.x and hadoop 1.2.1 on single machine.

I configure seed.txt, conf/regex-urlfilter.txt and run command

```
 crawl urls/seed.txt TestCrawl http://localhost:8088/solr/ 2
```

Then I want to change rules in conf/regex-urlfilter.txt

I changed it in 2 files:

```
~$ find . -name 'regex-urlfilter.txt' 
./webcrawer/apache-nutch-2.2.1/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt
./webcrawer/apache-nutch-2.2.1/runtime/local/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt
```

Then I run

```
  crawl urls/seed.txt TestCrawl2 http://localhost:8088/solr/ 2
```

But changes in regex-urlfilter.txt doesn't affect.

Hadoop report that it use file.

```
cat /home/hadoop/data/hadoop-unjar6761544045585295068/regex-urlfilter.txt
```

When I see content of file I see old file

How to force hadoop to use new config?

Answer (score 0):

This settings stored in arhive file

```
/home/hadoop/webcrawer/apache-nutch-2.2.1/build/apache-nutch-2.2.1.job
```

Run

```
ant clean
ant runtime
```

to replace it with new settings or edit arhive file /home/hadoop/webcrawer/apache-nutch-2.2.1/build/apache-nutch-2.2.1.job

Comment: I have the same problem but with nutch-site.xml, but ant clean doesn't work. Any other idea?